# Jquery: On execution of $("#divId").droppable({over: function(), how can I have an if-else function execute with random variables and functions?

Tags: jquery, html

Most of my code is "working" how I want it besides for some basic css that I need to tweak. On the execution of $("#divId").droppable({over: function() in my code, I want 2 other functions and have one of them be executed randomly on out:function() that is executed in the droppable.() 


(I am New to all coding languages, so bear with me.)


This is what I have working . . .

```
    $("#droppable").droppable({
    over: function() {
        $(this).find('p').html('Reading...');
    },

    out: function() {
        $(this).find('p').html('Please Swipe Again At This Website To Enter');
    },

    revert: function() {
        $(this).find('p').html('');
    },

    drop: function() {
        $(this).find('p').html('Error Reading Your Card');

    }
});
```

This is what I am working on trying to do . . . 
I want a random variable on the out function to "choose" one function or the other to execute. One of the functions hides some divs and makes one appear the other just changes the text in the paragraph in #droppable. This code looks setup correctly, but I am sure there is some syntax error I am not catching.

```
 $("#droppable").droppable({
    over: function() {
        $(this).find('p').html('Reading...');
    },

    out: function() {
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);

        if (number == 2) {
            $('#draggable, #draggable2, #droppable, #upperSwiper, #swiper').hide();
            $('#hi').show();
        } else {
            $(this).find('p').html('Please Swipe Again At This Website To Enter');
        },

    revert: function() {
        $(this).find('p').html('');
    },

    drop: function() {
        $(this).find('p').html('Error Reading Your Card');

    }
});
```

This is my working code, the css is a bit off because of the size of the snippet code box and the card snaps to the top so ignore that, but it works how I want it to besides for the mentioned function(s) above. You swipe the card through the area, and certain messages appear depending on how the draggable object reacts to the droppable area.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    containment: 'body',
    revert: function(dropped) {
      var $draggable = $(this),
        hasBeenDroppedBefore = $draggable.data('hasBeenDropped'),
        wasJustDropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "droppable";
      if (wasJustDropped) {
        // revert, it's in the droppable
        return true;
      } else {
        if (hasBeenDroppedBefore) {
          // don't rely on the built in revert, do it yourself
          $draggable.animate({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
          }, 'slow');
          return false;
        } else {
          // just let the build in work, although really, you could animate to 0,0 here as well
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  });





  $("#droppable").droppable({
    over: function() {
      $(this).find('p').html('Reading...');
    },

    out: function() {
      $(this).find('p').html('Please Swipe Again At This Website To Enter');
    },

    revert: function() {
      $(this).find('p').html('');
    },

    drop: function() {
        $(this).find('p').html('Error Reading Your Card');

      }
      //  random generated function I am trying to make
      /*   $("#droppable").droppable({
     over: function() {
            $(this).find('p').html('Reading...');
        },
        
        out: function() {
        var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
     
      if (number == 2) {
       $('#draggable, #draggable2, #droppable, #upperSwiper, #swiper').hide();
       $('#hi').show();
      } else {
       $(this).find('p').html('Please Swipe Again At This Website To Enter');
         },
        revert: function() {
          $(this).find('p').html('');
            },

        drop: function() {
        $(this).find('p').html('Error Reading Your Card');
              });
});  
            */
  });
});
```

```css
#hi {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
}
div.blackBar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 23px;
  top: 75%;
}
div.frontSwiper {
  background-color:
  /* #A9A9A9 */
  transparent;
  width: 85%;
  height: 65px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  z-index: ;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
body {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
#swiper {
  background-color:
  /* #b8b8b8*/
  transparent;
  width: 34%;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  Top: 200%;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
#upperSwiper {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 34%;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  Top: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
#droppable {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  Height: 300px;
  border-Width: 1px;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-al100: center;
  left: 50%;
}
#draggable,
#draggable2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  border-Width: 0px;
  background-image: none;
  left: 60%;
  background-color: #FFD700;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 91% 0, 100% 14%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 91% 0, 100% 14%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  z-index;
  -1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p style="font: italic bold 10px/15px Arial, Sans-serif; width: 50%, position: fixed;"></p>

</div>

<div id="swiper">
  <div class="frontSwiper"></div>
  <div id="upperSwiper"></div>
</div>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <div class="blackBar"></div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The `out` function you commented out has a missing curly brace at the very end. Apart from that it seems to work.

Comment: Which out function are you referring to? The second block of code on my post? Can you be more specific on where I am missing my curly brace? at the end of the function or the code block?

Comment: The `out` function below `//  random generated function I am trying to make`

Comment: I edited the same function that you mentioned above, and put it into my code how I need it in the jquery. I edited the original post  under "// random generated function I am trying to make" so you can see. It doesn't work,  my draggable object isn't draggable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet seems to work. I decreased the chance of swiping success to 20% to make it easier to test. Is this what you intended to do?

```js
   $(function() {
   $("#draggable").draggable({
       containment: 'body',
       revert: function(dropped) {
           var $draggable = $(this),
               hasBeenDroppedBefore = $draggable.data('hasBeenDropped'),
               wasJustDropped = dropped && dropped[0].id == "droppable";
           if (wasJustDropped) {
               // revert, it's in the droppable
               return true;
           } else {
               if (hasBeenDroppedBefore) {
                   // don't rely on the built in revert, do it yourself
                   $draggable.animate({
                       top: 0,
                       left: 0
                   }, 'slow');
                   return false;
               } else {
                   // just let the build in work, although really, you could animate to 0,0 here as well
                   return true;
               }
           }
       }
   });




   $("#droppable").droppable({
       over: function() {
           $(this).find('p').html('Reading...');
       },

       out: function() {
           var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

           if (number == 1) {
               $('#draggable, #draggable2, #droppable, #upperSwiper, #swiper').hide();
               $('#hi').show();
           } else {
               $(this).find('p').html('Please Swipe Again At This Website To Enter');
           }
       },

       revert: function() {
           $(this).find('p').html('');
       },

       drop: function() {
           $(this).find('p').html('Error Reading Your Card');

       }
   });
   });
```

```css
#hi {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
}
div.blackBar {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 23px;
  top: 75%;
}
div.frontSwiper {
  background-color:
  /* #A9A9A9 */
  transparent;
  width: 85%;
  height: 65px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 95% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  z-index: ;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
body {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
#swiper {
  background-color:
  /* #b8b8b8*/
  transparent;
  width: 34%;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  Top: 200%;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
#upperSwiper {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 34%;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  Top: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
#droppable {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  Height: 300px;
  border-Width: 1px;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-al100: center;
  left: 50%;
}
#draggable,
#draggable2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 130px;
  border-Width: 0px;
  background-image: none;
  left: 60%;
  background-color: #FFD700;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 91% 0, 100% 14%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 91% 0, 100% 14%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  z-index;
  -1;
}
#hi{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="hi">Access granted!</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p style="font: italic bold 10px/15px Arial, Sans-serif; width: 50%, position: fixed;"></p>

</div>

<div id="swiper">
  <div class="frontSwiper"></div>
  <div id="upperSwiper"></div>
</div>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <div class="blackBar"></div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```